# 3D objects only visible when declared in the constructor

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I have an app for Android that displays a 3D cube on screen using OpenGL ES. I want the user to click on the screen and send a cube towards that point, originating in the main cube.

I handle the touch input like this:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    switch (e.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // Fetch the normalized coordinates from the cube
            Vec2 cubePos = mainCube.getPositionOnScreen();

            // Multiply in order to get the pixels
            int cubePixelX = (int)(cubePos.x * width);
            int cubePixelY = (int)(cubePos.y * height);

            // A vector for storing the touched part of the screen
            Vec2 pressedCoordinates = new Vec2(e.getX(), e.getY());

            // Calculate the angle from the middle of the cube and the touched coordinates (0 rad is straight up. [0...pi] anti-clockwise, [0...-pi] clockwise)
            double angle = Math.atan2(cubePixelX - pressedCoordinates.x, cubePixelY - pressedCoordinates.y);

            // Create a child cube from the main cube's position and the calculated angle
            ChildCube child = new ChildCube(mainCube.getPos());
            child.setMovementAngle(angle);
            childCubes.addElement(child);    // A Vector

            break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The Vector childCubes is called from onDrawFrame()

```
for (int i = 0; i < childCubes.size(); i++) {
    childCubes.elementAt(i).update();
    childCubes.elementAt(i).draw(mViewProjectionMatrix);
}
```

Just like mainCube

```
mainCube.update()
mainCube.draw(mViewProjectionMatrix);
```

The methods belonging to the child cubes are actually being called (I verify this in both the update() and draw() methods) but nothing is rendered on screen. If I instead declare a single child cube within onSurfaceCreated - which is the closest I have to a constructor - like this

```
cc = new ChildCube(mainCube.getPos());    // cc is declared a private variable of type ChildCube
childCubes.addElement(cc);
```

and then merely update the cube in onTouchEvent() when the screen is pressed like this

```
cc.setPos(mainCube.getPos());
cc.setMovementAngle(angle);
```

then I can see a perfectly rendered child cube. It seems like it's the new operator that causes it to not work. If I do this instead

```
cc = new ChildCube(mainCube.getPos());
cc.setMovementAngle(angle);
childCubes.addElement(cc);
```

then I still have nothing but my main cube on screen.

Why is "new" stopping my cubes from being rendered to screen? My OpenGL parts ought to be correct, since the cubes I add statically get rendered.

Comment: Are you making any OpenGL calls in the `ChildCube` constructor? If yes, they would be made in the wrong thread if you create an instance from the UI thread.

Comment: I was just about to edit this post when I saw your comment. I noticed that I get the following error "E/libEGL: call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)" when initializing the new childCube. I'll try to find a way to communicate across threads.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion but take a look inside the constructor for ChildCube and make sure you are setting the position correctly.  The difference I notice in the two pieces of code is in the one that works you have an explicit call to cc.setPos but in the one that doesn't work you are passing the position into the constructor.

Comment: Thanks, but the constructor simply calls setPos(), so there's no difference.

Comment: At the time of creation of the children both the static and inside the onTouchEvent, is the value of the mainCube.getPos() the same or does mainCube move itself?  At the time the angle is calculated during the creation of the child outside the event is the angle the same as it would be inside the event?  Is it possible the combination of the angle + starting position when inside the event is causing the child to render outside the visible space?

Comment: Yes, the position of mainCube is the same no matter where it is fetched. I stopped the movement of mainCube to ease my debugging.

As for the angle, it's only calculated in one place (i.e. within onToucheEvent()). Even when I create the childCube statically outside onTouchEvent(), I stil only set the angle and position in onTouchEvent().